# What are fireball gloves, and how do you get them?

Tags: candy-box-2

I hear a lot of people talking about this, and I have no idea what it is. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Fireball gloves presumably refers to the red enchanted leather gloves, which shoot fireballs everywhere while you're wearing them.

To get them, buy the leather gloves from the merchant in town, then throw a chocolate bar into the wishing well to enchant them. Select Red leather Gloves.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you! I guess I have them already, then. :)